# Jackson ObjectMapper : Issues with date serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, date, jackson, deserialization

I would like to **disable lenient** option in `Jackson Deserializer` to deserialize Date fields strictly.

> Basically, I would like the below code to throw Exception instead of
>   parsing `33-Aug-2016` as `02-Sep-2016`.

**1. Order.java**

```
package com.test.date;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

public class Order {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
    private Date orderDate;

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public String getFormattedDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        return "[ " + sdf.format(getOrderDate()) + " ]";
    }

}
```

**2. TestJackson.java**

```
package com.test.date;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestJackson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException,
            JsonMappingException, IOException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(sdf);
        Order order = mapper.readValue("{\"orderDate\" : \"33-Aug-2016\"}",
                Order.class);
        System.out.println(order.getFormattedDate());

    }

}
```

**Output**

> [ 02-Sep-2016 ]

I can implement my own Deserializer class to do this, but I am looking for some annotation based or object mapper settings approach.

**UPDATE:**

I decided to go with custom Deserializer implementation and found another issue, but with **Serialization** now. The updated codes are for  as shown below:

**1. Order.java**

```
package com.test.date;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

public class Order {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
    private Date orderDate;

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getFormattedDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        return "[ " + sdf.format(getOrderDate()) + " ]";
    }

}
```

With custom deserializer, validation of dates work perfectly. However, serialization of the same object has issues. Please see below:

**2. TestJackson.java**

```
package com.test.date;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestJackson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException,
            JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Order order = mapper.readValue("{\"orderDate\" : \"22-Aug-2016\"}",
                Order.class);


        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(order));

    }

}
```

**Output**

> {"orderDate":"21-Aug-2016"}

**From where does this one day difference come into picture?**

Is it mandatory to provide custom implementation of `Serializer` if we use a custom `Deserializer`?

Answer (score 1):

The `@JsonFormat` annotation on the property overrides the `SimpleDateFormat` registered with the `ObjectMapper`. Get rid of the `@JsonFormat` and Jackson will use only the supplied `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the date and fail because of the

```
sdf.setLenient(false);
```

As far as I know, `@JsonFormat` does not have a `Feature` you can set to control leniency.

Comment: This works as long as all `Date` fields follow the same pattern. Is it possible to use a different pattern for a different date field without `@JsonFormat`?

Comment: @jnanthak You're out of luck afaik. Review where your dates are coming from and see if you can fix them at the source.

Comment: I decided to implement a custom `Deserializer`, but now there's a new issue with `Serialization`. There's a one day difference, please check my updated post.

Comment: As of Jackson 2.9+, there is a Feature to control leniency: `@JsonFormat(lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)`