# Jackson date deserialization - "invalid" day of month

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am using `Spring Boot` with `Jackson` serializing/deserializing JSON requests/responses. I have come accross a behaviour when trying to deserialize `Date` in ISO format that I would like to avoid.

When I use an invalid day of month or month of year, Jackson handles it by adding the extra number of days/months to the date.

For instance

```
{
    "date": "2018-02-40T15:00:00+01:00"
}
```

is deserialized as `Mon Mar 12 15:00:00 CET 2018`

Or

```
{
    "date": "2018-14-20T15:00:00+01:00"
}
```

as `Wed Feb 20 15:00:00 CET 2019`

Is there a way to enforce a validation somehow? I was looking at the list of [Serialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features) and [Deserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features) features but I was not able to find any that could influence this behaviour.

I am using the old Java Date API - `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answers pointed me the right direction. Jackson supports leniency configuration using the `@JsonFormat` annotation since `2.9+`.

```
@JsonFormat(lenient = OptBoolean.FALSE)
```

So all I had to do was to override the value of the `jackson.version` property in POM as I am using the `Spring Boot` parent POM.

```
<jackson.version>2.9.4</jackson.version>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using the old API, turn on strict mode by calling [`setLenient(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient-boolean-) on the [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) associated with the [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) you're using.

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+01:00"); 
sdf.setLenient(false);
objectMapper.setDateFormat(sdf);
```

A similar question: [Jackson ObjectMapper : Issues with date serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001693/jackson-objectmapper-issues-with-date-serialization-and-deserialization)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you using `spring-boot`,
You can create a configuration to your `ObjectMapper`

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+01:00");
        simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
        mapper.setDateFormat(simpleDateFormat);

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

And then everytime you want yo use just `inject` your `ObjectMapper`

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;
```